# In Neo4j 2.0, can numbers be labels?

Tags: neo4j

I read in the documentation that labels can be string or numbers. However, using only numbers gives an error:

```
start u=node(5) set u:1234 return labels(u);
```

The error is:

```
Invalid input '1': expected whitespace or an identifier (line 1, column 23)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any non-empty unicode string can be used as a label name. In Cypher, you may need to use the backtick (`) syntax to avoid clashes with Cypher identifier rules.

Here is the source of that: [source](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/graphdb-neo4j-labels.html)

I think you are running into a Cypher conflict. If you do this it should work:

```
start u=node(5) 
set u:`1234`
return labels(u);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and finally i found the solution

use grave accent(`)

use `insert your number` inside it